# Does struts loads all action classes configured in struts-config file during server start up?

Tags: struts-1

This is my first post on any technical portal... 
Kindly any one help me in understanding struts configurations a little deeper...
I have one doubt in struts 1.x ...

Does ActionServlet loads all action classes configured in struts-config.xml during server startup?

Actually, i have a struts application having almost 20 action classes configured in a single struts-config.xml file. Deployable in jboss 5.1.

Server taking a little extra time (around 2 mins) to get started with application deployed.

And iam not sure whether it is because of server taking time to load all classes or some thing else...

Kindly help me.
Also please suggest some good articles to learn struts internals.

Thanks.

Comment: Even if it *did* load "almost 20 action classes", unless you're doing something really weird in them, it wouldn't add 2m to startup time.

Comment: Hi Dave Newton, thanks for your reply. I've tried an other struts application with 3 actions classes, and found that they were not load unless we request for them explicitly.